# byobu (tmux) hangs on startup

Tags: crash, freeze, tmux, byobu

Yesterday, I was happily using Byobu/tmux (byobu version 5.74, tmux 2.0) with zsh as shell on my machine. Starting from this morning on, every byobu session just hangs after a small time interval and does not accept any input anymore. I start the session and then, for a while (around 0-15 seconds), I see the clock updating in the status bar - and suddenly it stops and I cannot do anything apart from killing tmux.

I already deleted ~/.byobu which did not change anything. Also changing my shell back to bash did not result in any further success... Running byobu as root does not exhibit the problem, switching to screen as backend also fixes it.

When running byobu with strace, the last lines of the log before the crash are

```
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 2, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=6, revents=POLLIN}])
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 5
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 7
close(5)                                = 0
close(7)                                = 0
recvmsg(6, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\317\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\377\377\377\377", 65535}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 16
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 2, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=6, revents=POLLOUT}])
sendmsg(6, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\320\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\377\377\377\377", 16}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 16
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 2, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(4, "a", 1, 0, NULL, NULL)      = 1
[ last two lines repeated 20 times ]
```

I can also attach the complete trace if that helps, or provide other debugging data if told how to :)

Comment: Interesting.  5.74 is an interesting version choice.  It's not one of the major releases in any of the Linux distros, that I'm aware.  Can you reproduce with the latest upstream release, or the latest release in your distro?  FWIW, I'm the author and maintainer of Byobu.

Comment: I just compiled version 5.94 in which the problem seems even more prominent. Starting byobu hangs directly without evening showing the byobu interface...

Comment: I just reset tmux to the package maintainer version 1.8 (uninstalled the manually compiled version 2.0) and now the problem seems to have disappeared, for now... It is still strange that only my user's byobu was affected, `sudo byobu` worked nicely before...

Comment: Good to know, thanks for following up.  It's likely a permissions issue, perhaps something in /dev/shm, where the distro version of tmux 1.8 sets up those permissions properly in the package maintainer scripts, but your self compiled one does not do so with a simple 'make install'?

Comment: Hmm, that might be the case... I will try to explore that a bit further tomorrow. Any hints on how I could find out more which permissions are concerned? I would really like to use tmux 2.0 as I use a couple of its new features in my scripts...

Comment: Alright, the problem definitely seems to be related to tmux 2.0. Upgrading to it triggers the problem, downgrading fixes it. Can you please give me some hints how I can debug this issue further? I really like using byobu but without tmux 2.0, I have to drop it :(

Comment: Please start by opening at bug at http://bugs.launchpad.net/byobu and let's move the debugging conversation there.  StackExchange is great for answering questions, but definitely not for debugging.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to reproduce this.  I'm using the development version of Ubuntu, wily 15.10, with byobu 5.92 and tmux 2.0-3.

Comment: I created a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/byobu/+bug/1489765